# CodIgniter CSRF error when submitting with disabled textfield

Tags: codeigniter, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a search form in navigation created with form_open() and the action from the search controller. Now when I want to submit something and disable the form for visualize a processing operation site CodeIgniter shows:

**An Error Was Encountered**
The action you have requested is not allowed.

**View File 4 Example:**

```
 <?php echo form_open(array('class' => 'searchform')); ?>
 <input type="text" name="search" value="..." />
 <input type="submit" name="s" value="..." />
 </form>
```

**JS Code:**

```
 $('form.searchform').submit(function()
 {
     $('form.searchform input').attr('disabled', 'true');
 });
```

Comment: It seem to be a problem if I disable the text element after submit and not that the request came from another controller. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: you need to post some code for us to review.

Comment: This is intended for actions submitted from sites other than your main application. If you need this kind of behaviour for external requests I think that you may disable csrf protection on the controller that will implement your search form logic. Of course that can be a security issue if its not implemented correctly.

Comment: Hi I edit the originally question and add an example. Hope you understand the problem. Thanks 4 your help!